# Reading Data from Data Grid View

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have filled a datagridview with datasource, my SQL query is in it. I didn't use a storedprocedure or anything like that. It displays data well but I couldn't use data from gridview. For example, `gridview1.selectedRow.cells[0].Text` and similar methods is not working?  Is there anybody can help me about this?

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <h3>Gridview with Filtering</h3>
        <div class="GridviewDiv">
        <table style="width: 540px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" class="GridviewTable">
            <tr >
                <td style="width: 40px;">
                    ID
                </td>
                <td style="width: 120px;" >
                    First Name
                </td>
                <td style="width: 120px;">
                    Last Name
                </td>
                <td style="width: 130px;">
                    Department
                </td>
                <td style="width: 130px;">
                    Location
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
                <td style="width: 40px;">
                </td>
                <td style="width: 120px;">
                </td>
                <td style="width: 120px;">
                </td>
                <td style="width: 130px;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddldepartment" DataSourceID="dsPopulateDepartment" AutoPostBack="true"
                        DataValueField="department" runat="server" Width="120px" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 130px;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLocation" DataSourceID="dsPopulateLocation" AutoPostBack="true"
                        DataValueField="location" runat="server" Width="120px" Font-Size="11px" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="All" Value="%"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True"
                        AllowSorting="true" DataSourceID="dsGridview" Width="540px" PageSize="10" CssClass="Gridview">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="Sort" SortExpression="id" ItemStyle-Width="40px"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="Sort" SortExpression="FirstName"
                                ItemStyle-Width="120px" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Sort" SortExpression="LastName"
                                ItemStyle-Width="120px" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Sort" SortExpression="Department"
                                ItemStyle-Width="130px" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Sort" SortExpression="Location"
                                ItemStyle-Width="130px" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsGridview" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EvonetConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [T_Employees]" FilterExpression="Department like '{0}%'
            and Location like '{1}%'">
            <FilterParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter Name="Department" ControlID="ddldepartment" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                <asp:ControlParameter Name="Location" ControlID="ddllocation" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            </FilterParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateDepartment" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EvonetConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT Department from [T_Employees]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPopulateLocation" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EvonetConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT Location FROM [T_Employees]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

using the Column Names

```
dataGridView.Rows[4].Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
```

if you want to iterate through each row then,

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid.Rows)
    {

         foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            string value = cell.Value.ToString();

        }
    }
```

Also, you can do the following to achieve what you want

```
string name = (string)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;
```

Comment: in the foreach section, how would i tell it to use a specific column of cells? would it be "string value = cell[0].Value.ToString();" ?

Answer (score 1):

if you use SelectionChanged event of datagrid. then u can try it

```
    private void dataGrid1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                object item = dataGrid1.SelectedItem;
                txtRegId.Text = (dataGrid1.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text;
                MessageBox.Show(txtName.Text);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ***post back events*** and parameters to get the selected value.

Get a read on **[this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/how-to-get-the-selected-row-in-gridview-using-Asp-Net/)** it is a tutorial about your question